# Can't save data or settings in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm new to VirtualBox. Someone helped me set up a Fedora 16 installation on VirtualBox.

The problem is that I can't save anything. I first tried setting up LAMP and installed Apache and MySQL from the command line and it worked. It said "completed", and when I typed

```
rpm -q mysql
```

it found the package.

But when I rebooted the machine (by clicking the restart button INSIDE Fedora, not on the VirtualBox screen) all the changes were lost. The same happened when I tried saving a file to the desktop.

What settings need to be changed to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be something wrong with your install. Make sure that you're not booting to a 'LiveCD' and that Fedora is in fact *installed* on to the VHD. It could be that the CD is still 'in' the VM, check to make sure that the .iso used to install Fedora has be unmounted.
[image]

When I first started using virtualization, I blamed *everything* on VirtualBox. Now I've found that it's best to begin your troubleshooting from within. Treat it like a 'real' machine. Did you take the CD out before rebooting? Is Fedora installed properly? Asking the easy questions first would've saved me a lot of time on the VirtualBox forums hunting for things I had screwed up myself.

If the disc won't unmount, it is probably in use by the system. Shut down the machine and then unmount the .iso.

Comment: I don't have real cd, I just have a iso image on my computer. So I can't take a cd out before rebooting...

Comment: And which settings exactly am I supposed to be looking at to see if Fedora is installed correctly? It loads up fine. The only issue I ever saw (and dismissed since I didn't know what it meant) was that Gnome 3 wasn't able to load properly. Can this be the issue somehow?

Comment: Updated with screen shot of what I'm talking about.

Comment: TBH, I'm not too familiar with Fedora. But I did run in to an 'installation' of Ubuntu once that was actually just a LiveCD on a VHD.

Comment: I can't see your screenshot, its just an empty box.

Comment: If it makes a difference, the iso I am using is Fedora-16-i686-Live-Desktop.iso

Comment: Ok, I just tried that. It says that it is unable to unmount the CD/DVD image. What steps do I need to do now?

Comment: You need to shutdown the machine then unmount.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ISO from your properties in VirtualBox. You are running it in Live mode.
Settings > Storage > Controller > YOUR_ISO>PATH