# can't unmount cd image in virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

This is a followup question from [Can't save data or settings in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/453136/cant-save-data-or-settings-in-virtualbox)

In summary: I can't save any data in my fedora inside of Virtualbox. I went to the devices tab, then cd/dvd devices, then remove disk from virtual drive, and I got the error that it was unable to unmount the cd image. 
It seems that I did something wrong with my installation. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shut down the machine then unmount the CD. My guess is (still) that you're booting to the LiveCD. It can't unmount because it's in use, because it *is* the operating system. Shut down the virtual machine and unmount the drive, then start it back up and see if you can save anything.

Once the machine is powered off, select the machine and click settings.
[image]

Select Storage, click on the iso image (I used TRK because it was handy), and then click unmount.
[image]

Respond to the dialog box, press ok, and voila!

No bootable medium indicates that you were running off the LiveCD all along. Follow one of the [many](http://www.zealfortechnology.com/2011/11/fedora-16-install-guide-virtual-machine.html) [guides](http://www.sysprobs.com/install-fedora-16-virtualbox-guest-additions-get-working-gnome-shell-inside-virtual-machine) [online](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBRx-4ZO_NI) to install Fedora properly, or simply [download a vdi](http://virtualboxes.org/images/fedora/) and [import it into VirtualBox.](http://oswaldatwork.thetaoofamp.com/2009/11/importing-a-vdi-in-virtualbox/)

I'd write these up but it seems redundant and beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: How do you unmount the drive? I am new to virtual box.

Comment: It seems I may have led you astray last time. VBox closes the VM window once the machine shuts down. I'm not used to this behavior.

Comment: Well, when I followed your directions, now it wont load, it says FATAL: not bootable medium found. System halted. This would make sense, if I was running off the cd and then deleted the cd player then its finished. So, what can I do now to really install it (as well as get my cd device back)?

Comment: You're probably better off starting with a new VM.

Comment: Thanks! I went the easy way and just downloaded the vdi and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit all the xml files, the main one and the machine(s) referring to them. Just search for the uuid.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, as I said above, I am very new to virtual box.